# Node.js & the instagram API, 'Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8'

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram

I am doing a simple instagram API call with the http node.js module.  Just a simple request like this:

```
getJSON : function(options, on_result, on_error) {

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

        var output = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
            return output += chunk;
        });

        return res.on('end', function() {
            var obj = JSON.parse(output);
            on_result(res.statusCode, obj);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        on_error(err);
    });

    return req.end();
}
```

The on_result function just stringifies it with JSON.stringify, and sends it across a web socket with this function:

```
var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

When I start the node server and point my browser to my url, I get this from chrome and firefox:

> Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.

I had absolutely no problems running this yesterday.

In the http 'on data' function, I am logging out the data to the console, and what I see onscreen looks ok except certain escape characters like these:

```
"text":"\ud83d\ude1d\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\udc4f\ud83d\udc8b"
"full_name":"\ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf9\u21e8\u261eSara\u261c\u21e6\ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf9"
```

Then, when it gets JSON stringified, these escape sequences turn into this:

```
"text":"<d83d><de1d><d83d><de02><d83d><dc4f><d83d><dc8b>"
"full_name":"<d83c><ddee><d83c><ddf9>â¨âSaraââ¦<d83c><ddee><d83c><ddf9>"
```

Which explains why the browsers complain about UTF-8.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might need to set the accept-type in the request.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but have already set 'Accept' : 'application/json' and 'Accept-Charset' : 'utf-8'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that the data is coming from instagram like this and there is not much that can be done, except to try escaping or removing the non utf-8 characters.  Since only certain fields are like this and my application has no need for those fields, I can get around it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to escape \u as follows:

```
    return res.on('end', function() {
        var escaped_output = output.replace(/\\u/g, "\\\\u");  //<--
        var obj = JSON.parse(escape_output);
    });
```

Also, why do you convert 'output' to object and then back to string and not pass it to the websocket as received at the response.

Comment: Because just sending JSON string from the API to the browser is not my ultimate goal, there will be other things done with the object before stringifying it during the response to the browser.